# Android - Post content null

Tags: android, json, post

I'm getting the inserted contacts by the user and post it on the db. When i post, sometimes the content is null and sometimes not. Why?

This code uploads the name contact and the phone contact using post, i also send the id, the 
token. The content gives me null when i upload on the db. Sometimes I'm getting content : null and sometimes it's right...

```
public void upload(JSONObject jobject, int id, Context c) {

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nvp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    DBupload upload = new DBupload();
    Database db = new Database(c);
    DatosRegistro dr = new DatosRegistro(c);

    nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("content", new String().valueOf(jobject)));
    nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", dr.hash_final(
            dr.token_secret(dr.mail(), "mail"), jobject.toString())));
    nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id + ""));

    JSONObject json2 = upload.UploaData(nvp,
            "url");

    try {
        if (json2.getInt("error") == 1) {

        } else {
            db.open();
            db.contact_table(name, phoneNumber);
            db.close();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```